Elastic net regression with small datasets
I have a dataset of 18 cases and 10 predictors. Some of these predictors are highly correlated, which means I am dealing with multicollinearity.
I wanted to do a regression analysis and found elastic net regression as a good method to do this. However, is it appropriate for such a small dataset? Or should I consider something else (or no regression analysis at all)?
Also, I tried using R for elastic net regression (train function) but I'm not sure at which value to set the tunelength parameter for such a small dataset.
Any help would be appreciated.

What is your goal here?  If you do this analysis, what do you hope the outcome would be?

Eighteen cases and ten variables has me thinking of this.

I just wanted to see if my independent variables could, in any way, predict the dependent variables.
